# Как записать данные из форм на разных страницах в одну строку БД?

Tags: php, sql

у меня есть форма регистрации с несколькими полями: Имя, Email, и тд. После после того как я заполняю поля и нажимаю на кнопку "NEXT" данные заполняются в бд, и появляется новая форма уже на другой странице в том же стиле с другими полями: Фото, О себе и тд. и тоже нажимаю "NEXT", и данные тоже заносятся в БД, но проблема в том, что уже в новой строке, т.е. поля Имя, Email остаются пустыми. Как сделать так чтобы все заносилось в одну строку. Если вам что-то не понятно, я уточню
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну тебе же уже [ответили](https://qna.habr.com/q/883419). Думаешь, на другом сайте ответ будет какой-то другой?

Comment: @Ипатьев ты из фбр?

Comment: @ВадимАлександру то есть чтобы увидеть что вопрос один и тот же, надо быть сотрудником из внутренних органов? Простому программисту не под силу? :)

Comment: @Ипатьев Я о том, что нужно чекать все форумы где могут задавать вопросы такого рода.